# what triggers a QTreeView to ask for a SizeHintRole in the QAbstractItemModel.data() function

Tags: python, pyqt, qtreeview, qabstractitemmodel

I have made a few different applications using `TreeViews` and `AbstractItemModels` but I came across something I do not understand.  I realized that the view was calling the model's `data` function asking for a `Size` for the items as the role was SizeHintRole ([see Qt Documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#ItemDataRole-enum)).  In all of the other cases, I don't ever recall needing to worry about returning a `size` for the `data` function.  In the code below, I erroneously expected that `data` would just be looking for the items in the list, and if you uncomment the first line, the view displays nothing because in fact the view is asking for the `sizeHint` of the indices.

My question is, what circumstances require this?  I have never needed to provide a `sizeHint` before and I don't understand when it is required and when it is not.

window when the first line is commented

[image]

window when the first line is enabled, thus ignore the sizeHint request

[image]

```py
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets

class TreeList:
    def __init__(self):
        self._items = list()

class TreeModel(QtCore.QAbstractItemModel):
    def __init__(self, root, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.root = root

    def index(self, row: int, column: int, parent: QtCore.QModelIndex = ...) -> QtCore.QModelIndex:
        if not self.hasIndex(row, column, parent):
            return QtCore.QModelIndex()

        if not parent.isValid():
            pointer = self.root  # type: TreeList
            child = pointer._items[row]
        else:
            child = None

        return self.createIndex(row, column, child)

    def addItem(self, layer):
        row = len(self.root._items)
        self.beginInsertRows(QtCore.QModelIndex(), row, row)
        self.root._items.append(layer)
        self.endInsertRows()

    def parent(self, child: QtCore.QModelIndex) -> QtCore.QModelIndex:
        return QtCore.QModelIndex()

    def rowCount(self, parent: QtCore.QModelIndex = ...) -> int:
        if parent.isValid():
            return 0
        else:
            return len(self.root._items)

    def columnCount(self, parent: QtCore.QModelIndex = ...) -> int:
        return 1

    def hasChildren(self, parent: QtCore.QModelIndex = ...) -> bool:
        return False if parent.isValid() else True

    def data(self, index: QtCore.QModelIndex, role: int = ...):
        # return self.root._items[index.row()]
        if role == QtCore.Qt.SizeHintRole:
            print(index.isValid(), index.row(), index.column())
            return QtCore.QSize(100, 20)
        else:
            return self.root._items[index.row()]

    def flags(self, index: QtCore.QModelIndex):
        return QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsSelectable


class StackTreeView(QtWidgets.QTreeView):
    def __init__(self, data=None, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setModel(TreeModel(data))

    def addItem(self, layer):
        self.model().addItem(layer)


def test():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    data = TreeList()
    data._items = ['one', 'two']
    sys.excepthook = sys.__excepthook__
    tree_view = StackTreeView(data)
    tree_view.show()
    tree_view.addItem('three')
    tree_view.addItem('four')
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Returning `self.root._items[index.row()]` by default for all roles makes no sense at all. You should always explicitly check the role and only ever return a value that is appropriate *for that specific role*. If you don't have data specific to a role, you should return `None` in PyQt (which is equivalent to an invalid `QVariant` in C++).

See the [Model Subclassing Reference](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/model-view-programming.html#model-subclassing-reference) for an outline of the basic requirements.